# Magento - Include a block from extension in phtml template file

Tags: php, magento

I've installed an extension which generates an auto related product block. Unfortunately for some reason this wants to create its own block rather than replace the native one (the extension seems somewhat broken in this sense?)

Anyway, after contacting their support - I'm getting no responses and now I'm stuck having to fix this myself.

First step for me would be to include this block in our catalog/product/view.phtml file. Having inspected the extension code (layout file) I can see the following:

```
<block type="autorelatedproduct/autorelatedproduct" name="autorelatedproduct" template="autorelatedproduct/autorelatedproduct.phtml" />
```

Having included this in my catalog.xml file under the content in product view and then trying to call this block through the template. I am getting nothing new.

Would anyone be able to help me out and tell me how I could include this block in my template?

As always, any help is always appreciated!

Comment: On which Magento version are you working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could call this in your local.xml like

```
 <?xml version="1.0"?>
    <layout version="0.1.0">
       <catalog_product_view>
        <reference name="content"> 
            <block type="autorelatedproduct/autorelatedproduct" name="autorelatedproduct" template="autorelatedproduct/autorelatedproduct.phtml" />    
        </reference>
      </catalog_product_view>
   </layout>
```

If you want to place it specific position you can try

```
 <reference name="product.info">
```

and call it in view.phtml like
  getChildHtml('yourblock');

Comment: Hi there, unfortunately this did not work for me. When I try using: echo $this->getChildHtml('autorelatedproduct'); To call this in my view.phtml file it does not create anything.

Comment: you don't have to do that, it will directly add the template file on product page. make your own theme and add layout folder->then add local.xml. Paste the above code

Comment: Actually! I just enabled my template hints and can see the block being called. Although empty? Having inspected the XML of the extension further I can see: `<block type="autorelatedproduct/autorelatedproduct" name="autorelatedproduct.inside">
        <action method="setBlockPosition">
          <block_position>2</block_position>
        </action>
      </block>
 ` Would this be needed as well?

Comment: Ok well as it stands I can see the block, although empty. Do you think I would need to include the block above as well?

Comment: Thanks, I did this and it shows. However not inside the view container but after it finishes (if that makes sense) Do you now how I could move this over to the content area?

Comment: Where do you want to place it

Comment: Well the website is: http://homecolours.eits.info/marble-delight-wall-clock-copper-black.html 

It is currently in development. As this extension does not natively replace the native related products block (annoying) and generates its own block. I'm going to have to remove the native one and re-style this one to make it look similar to the existing. But first it needs to be placed in the same spot.

Comment: Unfortunately, adding the new reference within the content reference makes the block content disappear. Any ideas to why this may be?

Comment: in <block as="myblock"/> add this line and then in view.phtml call <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('myblock') ?>

Comment: I have tried this, unfortunately does not show (also noticed the existing block the extension puts in also disappears) I'm guessing it is because both blocks have the same name? autorelatedproduct.inside

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/122514/discussion-between-shrikant-and-aasim).

Answer (score 0):

```
<catalog_product_view translate="label">
    <reference name="content">
        <block type="catalog/product_view" name="product.info" template="catalog/product/view.phtml">
            <block type="autorelatedproduct/autorelatedproduct" name="autorelatedproduct" template="autorelatedproduct/autorelatedproduct.phtml" />
        </block>
      </catalog_product_view>
```

and call this  using  echo $this->getChildHtml('autorelatedproduct');
in view.phtml

Comment: Actually! I just enabled my template hints and can see the block being called. Although empty? Having inspected the XML of the extension further I can see: `<block type="autorelatedproduct/autorelatedproduct" name="autorelatedproduct.inside">
        <action method="setBlockPosition">
          <block_position>2</block_position>
        </action>
      </block>
 ` Would this be needed as well?

Comment: Yes you need to place it in your xml